# Edit whole site using CKEditor

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I'm trying to edit an entire Html email (html, body, tags etc.) using the CKEditor (and thus all the Html code is inside a textarea).

When I load the Html via ajax and place it inside the textarea, the outer page gets some of the properties of the loaded page (for example, I can see the background color change).

Is there any way to avoid this?

I'm using CakePHP, and I have this inside my  section:

```
    if($this->request->params['controller'] == 'designs')
    {
        echo $this->Html->script('ckeditor/ckeditor.js');
        echo '<script>var enableCkeditor = true;</script>';
    } else
    {
        echo '<script>var enableCkeditor = false;</script>';
    }
```

later I do the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

    if(enableCkeditor)
    {
       CKEDITOR.replace('htmleditor');
    }
});
</script>
```

and later this (as part of a form)

```
<textarea name="html" id="htmleditor" class="ckeditor"><?php echo $thisHtml; ?></textarea>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to create an HTML email editor, so the Html I load has all the styles inline. Do you guys know of a good open source email Html editor?

Thanks

Comment: I think your idea is kind of wrong because the output will be most of times broken on outlook or lotus notes, if not in Hotmail or Gmail. Not a really good idea in my point of view...

Comment: It can be done somehow... sites like MailChimp edit email Html for a living.

Comment: Could you compartmentalize with an iframe?

Comment: I have used CKEditor that way and the main page doesn't get the properties of the edited page, so there's a bug in your code.

Comment: Added code to see if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the HTML inside your textarea via [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
<textarea name="html" id="htmleditor" class="ckeditor"><?php echo htmlentities($thisHtml); ?></textarea>
```

Any unencoded html between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` is evaluated as regular HTML, meaning both that you're producing an incredibly invalid HTML document and that  any script/stylesheet link tags will be evaulated and applied to your DOM.

Comment: Actually I don't have any text when it first loads, but instead I load the page via ajax using CKEditor's setData method, which should be Html. http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#setData

Comment: Yet, that's not what your code indicates. What is the content of `$thisHtml`?

Comment: It's always empty. I'm loading the content via ajax. This echo can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see the html of the hosting page as well as the loaded content, however I suspect you are loading elements with id's that duplicate the hosting page or loading inline css that applies to a style of the hosting page. Make sure your using distinct id and class names between the two bodies.